# merging part files in apache spark fast

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hdfs, blob

I have a folder in hdfs that contains 202 part files which is the output of a job.
The total size is 195GB. I want to merge all these files into single file in hdfs.
Is there any way to do this very fast.
We are using Microsoft azure cloud platform and spark distribution we are using is HDInsight.

we are tried some commands, all of which are taking lot of time.(4+ hours).
Please help.

```
sc.textFile("/Dataproviders/Temp/MDASHistory/KAI/Order/Output2/*").coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/Dataproviders/Temp/MDASHistory/KAI/Order/MergedFileSp.out") 

hdfs dfs -getmerge /Dataproviders/Temp/MDASHistory/KAI/Order/Output2/* final.dat

org.talend.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copyMerge(fs,
                        sourceDirPath_tFileOutputDelimited_1, fs,
                        targetFilePath_tFileOutputDelimited_1, false, job,
                        null, headerByteCount_tFileOutputDelimited_1);
```

Comment: Merging such large text files into one will effectively reduces parallelism. Because all that data has to come one of the executor (network bandwidth) and be written to disk (if hdfs then added network delay to send it to data nodes). Why do you want to merge them to a single file?

Comment: @shanmuga...we want to load this file to a table...on top of that reporting runs.

Comment: You want to load it to what kind of table?

Comment: SQL server DWH database